# Run a systemd service whenever no user is logged in

Tags: systemd

I have a service that runs batch jobs on a number of lab machines. The lab machines are desktop machines, and I want to run the service only if no user is currently logged in. That means:

- When a user logs in, the service should be stopped.
- When the last user logs out, the service should be started.

My current idea is to use `Conflicts=`, but this has a number of problems:

- The service is not started again when the last user logs out.
- Starting the service manually would lead to a forced logout of all users.
- I don't know how to glob instantiated services (i.e. I would need `Conflicts=user@*.service`)

How do I define such a systemd service without the problems above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Starting the service manually would lead to a forced logout of all users.

Instead of using `Conflicts=` in your service, create a new systemd target, `vacant.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=units that should run when users aren't logged in

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You might want your batch jobs or whatever to run in the time after systemd starts, but before users log in. If so, enable the new target: `systemctl enable vacant.target`. Perhaps you're wondering about the lack of `Conflicts=`, and having attempted this before, you're thinking:

> I don't know how to glob instantiated services (i.e. I would need Conflicts=user@*.service)

`Conflicts=` affects the conflicted and conflicting units in essentially the same way. Globbing is not possible, so create a drop-in with `systemctl edit 'user@.service'`:

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=vacant.target

[Service]
ExecStopPost=+/usr/local/bin/vacancy
```

Note the additional section that causes a script to run after each logout, addressing another problem:

> The service is not started again when the last user logs out.

Due to the leading `+`, the script `/usr/local/bin/vacancy` runs with the privilege to operate on systemd units:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start vacant.target if the list of logged-in users is empty.
[[ -z $(users) ]] && systemctl start vacant.target
```

Whatever service, timer, or other unit you want to run when no users are logged in, integrate this into the unit file:

```
[Unit]
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=vacant.target manual.target
```

Finally, enabling your unit will trigger it to run with the rest of vacant.target. `StopWhenUnneeded=yes` will prevent the manual starting of the unit. To work around this, create `manual.target`:

```
[Unit]
Description=units that normally run when users aren't logged in
```

Run your units manually with `systemctl start manual.target`.